# Import Data from SQL Server Database Into HTML Table

Tags: php, sql-server, loops, html-table

I have many rows in my DB table so I am unable to hardcode anything in. I am assuming I need some sort of loop that loops through the rows in the DB then displays it into my HTML table. Here is my code so far...could you tell me what I need to do?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stage Rebate Master HTML Table</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        $host="xxxxx";
        $dbName="xxxxx";
        $dbUser="xxxx";
        $dbPass="xxxxxxxxx";
        $dbh = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=".$host."; Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass); var_dump($dbh);

        if (!$dbh) {
            die("Connection failed: " . sqlsrv_connect_error());
        }
        echo "Connected successfully";

        $results = sqlsrv_query("SELECT * FROM Stage_Rebate_Master ORDER BY MR_ID ASC");

        $id = 'MR_ID';
        $name = 'MR_Name';
        $buyer = 'Buyer_ID';
        $poc_name = 'MR_POC_N';
        $poc_email = 'MR_POC_E';
        $poc_tel = 'MR_POC_P';
    ?>

    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <td>MR_ID</td>
        <td>MR_Name</td>
        <td>Buyer_ID</td>
        <td>MR_POC_N</td>
        <td>MR_POC_E</td>
        <td>MR_POC_P</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        while($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results)) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $rows['MR_ID']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
            <td><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        </tr>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You already have a loop on your code...also *what is the question here?*

Comment: I need to be able to get the data for the DB into the html table...the only thing i have displaying currently are the table headers

Comment: Can you post the output of this `var_dump($results );`

Comment: I pasted that code right before my while loop and i got `bool(false)`

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same....you are mixing PDO with sqlsrv_query...also the first parameter for sqlsrv_query in the connection...you either use one of those...take a look at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php

Comment: I copied the sqlsrv example they had there and I got an error in my connection so I think I need to stick with the PDO

Comment: Just a simple question...how much time do you have programming with php?

Comment: I am not the best with it but I am familiar with it and use it every once in while

Comment: Mmmm, ok with that...then you should realize that you are mixing pears with apples....you either do it full PDO or you do it with the sqlsrv methods, but mixed they are not going to work....If you decide to go full PDO I can show you how....but first make the choice!

Comment: lets go full PDO then!

Comment: Ok then...first, before I post an answer I need to check if your PDO connection is working; can you post the result of `var_dump($dbh);`

Comment: `object(PDO)#1 (0) { }`

Comment: Now replace your `$dbh` line with: `$dbh = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=".$host."; Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass); var_dump($dbh);` and post the result...also, you are trying to connect  to the sql server using Windows or Sql Authentication....

Comment: the result is the same as last...`object(PDO)#1 (0) { }`...I am connecting using SQL Authentication

Comment: And those user and password works using Management Studio, right....sorry for all my questions but `object(PDO)#1 (0) { }` means that there is not connection at all....

Comment: I just added an if statement to test the connection and it says it connected successfully

Comment: Can you update the code on your question...also check the result for `var_dump($dbh);`

Comment: I updated the code and am also still getting the same result from the var_dump

Comment: I just edited the comment....It works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124333/discussion-between-rataiczak24-and-hackerman).

Comment: I have the chat blocked...I am in the office now...but it works?

Comment: Well I copied it into my code and nothing seems to be happening....should I still keep all of my other code too?

Comment: In my foreach code, replace `$conn` with `$dbh`...it should be `foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) { print_r($row); }`

Comment: Not sure how I missed that...it looks like it works but it doesn't display in a table...its just a ton of data back to back

Comment: Ok we are good to go...I am going to post the answer, just wait like 5 minutes....

Comment: sounds good! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
<?php
$host="xxxxxxxx"; 
$dbName="xxxxxxx"; 
$dbUser="xxxxx"; 
$dbPass="xxxxxxxxx"; 

$dbh = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=".$host."; Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass); 
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Stage_Rebate_Master ORDER BY MR_ID ASC"; 
?>

<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
    <td>MR_ID</td>
    <td>MR_Name</td>
    <td>Buyer_ID</td>
    <td>MR_POC_N</td>
    <td>MR_POC_E</td>
    <td>MR_POC_P</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo intval($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Awesome works great...my only question is that the ID goes 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 etc...is there anyway to get rid of the .0?

Comment: Thank you very much!! Appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in saying that a loop is required.

Replace your while loop with the following:
`while ($rows = $results->fetch_assoc()){`

I would personally also add in some logic which will check if any data is returned, if not then display a message.

i.e.
`if($results->num_rows > 0)`

Comment: I used that new while loop and nothing happened

Comment: You are not identifying the underlying issues...I am not going to downvote your code, but, try a little bit harder

Comment: In the case of this not working, i would suggest rewriting your code to follow a more object orientated MySQLi approach. Doing this will make error diagnosis a little easier. For an example of this please see the following:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

EDIT: Thanks for the feedback @Hackerman